# No virtual disk image in Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to set up a Windows 7 VM on VirtualBox. But something is wrong and I cannot figure out why. Here are some steps I am trying:

1. I set up a VDI in the folder \VirtualBox VMs\Windows 7 (32-bit)
2. I get to here:

[image: No virtual optical disc file]

Clicking to the right of "SATA Port 1" produces no virtual optical disc files in the VM folder. I looked in that folder, and the only files there are the VDI files and two other files, neither of which is the VOD file.

3. I try to run the VM. I get to here:

[image: Again, no VOD]

There is no VOD to select. Thus, I get the "FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted" error. If I try to bypass the optical drive and boot from the virtual hard drive, I get a "FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted" error. So I can't run this VM yet.

How do I create this virtual optical disc and then use it to boot my VM?

Comment: The VDI is the disk. Why are you trying to mount a CD?

Comment: IDK. I just want the thing to run. TBH I'm not even sure what I'm doing.

Comment: How did you get a VDI? Did you install Windows 7 using an ISO file? You can't just "create a Windows VM in VirtualBox", and it immediately boots into Windows

Comment: Besides that, you're running Windows 10, do you really need windows 7?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to run some old games that require DVD-ROMs, and Win 10 will not run them.

Comment: Did you try running them in compatibility mode? What errors do you get when you do run them? Why do you think running a VM will get you good performance for playing games?

Comment: It is a known issue that Windows 10 does not allow SafeDisc to run, effectively negating the use of DVD-ROMs without some kind of workaround.

Comment: Have you actually installed Windows yet? You have to supply your own physical Windows Installation CD-ROM or your own image of one, then right click on the optical disk and tell it where that image is. Virtualbox doesn't provide installation disks for all possible OSes.

Comment: Ahh, thanks Mark, that must be the step I am lacking. Next up, to go find an image of Windows 7.

Comment: You won't find a free one. You must purchase a license

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu should have windows ISO file downloaded in your machine. when you click that button it open the windows explorer to you to choose ISO file. Yous should go to that file location in windows explorer and choose windows ISO file.